# Bitfields and alignment

Tags: c, bit-fields

Trying to pack data into a packet. This packet should be 64 bits. I have this:

```
typedef union {
  uint64_t raw;
  struct {
    unsigned int magic    : 8;
    unsigned int parity   : 1;
    unsigned int stype    : 8;
    unsigned int sid      : 8;
    unsigned int mlength  : 31;
    unsigned int message  : 8;
  } spacket;
} packet_t;
```

But it seems that alignment is not guaranteed. Because when I run this:

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const char *number_to_binary(uint64_t x)
{
    static char b[65];
    b[64] = '\0';

    uint64_t z;
    int w = 0;
    for (z = 1; w < 64; z <<= 1, ++w)
    {
        b[w] = ((x & z) == z) ? '1' : '0';
    }

    return b;
}

int main(void)
{
  packet_t ipacket;
  bzero(&ipacket, sizeof(packet_t));
  ipacket.spacket.magic = 255;
  printf("%s\n", number_to_binary(ipacket.raw));
  ipacket.spacket.parity = 1;
  printf("%s\n", number_to_binary(ipacket.raw));
  ipacket.spacket.stype = 255;
  printf("%s\n", number_to_binary(ipacket.raw));
  ipacket.spacket.sid = 255;
  printf("%s\n", number_to_binary(ipacket.raw));
  ipacket.spacket.mlength = 2147483647;
  printf("%s\n", number_to_binary(ipacket.raw));
  ipacket.spacket.message = 255;
  printf("%s\n", number_to_binary(ipacket.raw));
}
```

I get (big endian):

```
1111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111111111111111111111111000000011111111111111111111111111111110
1111111111111111111111111000000011111111111111111111111111111110
```

My `.mlength` field is lost somewhere on the right part although it should be right next to the `.sid` field.

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field) confirms it: *Alignment of the allocation unit that holds a bit field is **unspecified**.* But if this is the case, how do people are packing data into bit fields which is their purpose in the first place?

24 bits seems to be the maximum size the `.mlength` field is able to take before the `.message` field is kicked out.

Comment: Generally, you cannot rely on how the data in a bitfield is laid out. If you need need to pack multiple data into a word, you have to do the marshalling manually.

Comment: your struct is 32 * 6 bits... You should use chars instead .

Comment: Don't rely on a specific memory layout for C data structures. There are just too many implementation defined and compiler-specific parameters. As @FUZxxl wrote, use proper marshalling. With a good compiler, this is not necessarily slower.

Comment: @xvan: Using standard types is a bad idea. And `char` is even worse.

Comment: @Olaf Using standard types is *not* a bad idea if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @FUZxxl: OPs approach using fixed width types is already a good idea. W change that in favour of using types with implementation-defined range and signedness?

Comment: @Olaf Because the fixed width types might not be available everywhere and might not be needed either.

Comment: @FUZxxl: This question is about C and tagged C which implies standard C (see the info). And the C standard requires for **all** implementations to provide this header and specific types. If `uint8_t` etc. are not available, the reason is your architecture does not support the required widths or (for signed types) representation. Which will eventually break any code relying on the width for the standard types. Thus using `(u)intN_t` is another safety-net for your implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost everything about the layout of bit-fields is implementation-defined in the standard, as you'd find from numerous other questions on the subject on SO.  (Amongst others, you could look at [Questions about bitfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071252/questions-about-c-bitfields?rq=1) and especially [Bit field's memory management in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677235/bit-fields-memory-management-in-c)).

If you want your bit fields to be packed into 64 bits, you'll have to trust that your compiler allows you to use 64-bit types for the fields, and then use:

```
typedef union {
  uint64_t raw;
  struct {
    uint64_t magic    : 8;
    uint64_t parity   : 1;
    uint64_t stype    : 8;
    uint64_t sid      : 8;
    uint64_t mlength  : 31;
    uint64_t message  : 8;
  } spacket;
} packet_t;
```

As originally written, under one plausible (common) scheme, your bit fields would be split into new 32-bit words when there isn't space enough left in the current one.  That is, `magic`, `parity`, `stype` and `sid` would occupy 25 bits; there isn't enough room left in a 32-bit `unsigned int` to hold another 31 bits, so `mlength` is stored in the next `unsigned int`, and there isn't enough space left over in that unit to store `message` so that is stored in the third `unsigned int` unit.  That would give you a structure occupying `3 * sizeof(unsigned int)` or 12 bytes — and the union would occupy 16 bytes because of the alignment requirements on `uint64_t`.

Note that the standard does not guarantee that what I show will work.  However, under many compilers, it probably will work.  (Specifically, it works with GCC 5.3.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.4.)

Comment: But even then you can't depend on the order the bit-fields are laid out.  Change your compiler, and everything could change.  And to be precise, it's also implementation-defined whether or not a bit-field has to split into a new structure element when it can not fit into the current one - it might span elements.

Comment: Like I said, essentially everything except their existence is implementation defined.  The [Bit field's memory management in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677235/bit-fields-memory-management-in-c) question has an answer (from YT) quoting the standard, extensively, on the subject of bit fields.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your architecture and/or compiler your data will be aligned to different sizes. From your observations I would guess that you are seeing the consequences of 32 bit aligning. If you take a look at the sizeof your union and that is more than 8 bytes (64 bits) data has been padded for alignment.

With 32 bit alignment mlength and message will only be able to stay next to each other if they sum up to less than or equal 32 bits. This is probably what you see with your 24 bit limit.

If you want your struct to only take 64 bits with 32 bit alignment you will have to rearrange it a little bit. The single bit parity should be next to the 31 bit mlength and your 4 8 bit variables should be grouped together.