# Bit order in struct is not what I would have expected

Tags: c++, endianness, bit-fields

I have a framework which uses 16 bit floats, and I wanted to separate its components to then use for 32bit floats. In my first approach I used bit shifts and similar, and while that worked, it was wildly chaotic to read.

I then wanted to use custom bit sized structs instead, and use a union to write to that struct.

The code to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

union float16_and_int16
{
    struct
    {
        uint16_t    Mantissa : 10;
        uint16_t    Exponent : 5;
        uint16_t    Sign : 1;
    } Components;

    uint16_t bitMask;
};

int main()
{
    uint16_t input = 0x153F;

    float16_and_int16 result;
    result.bitMask = input;

    printf("Mantissa: %#010x\n", result.Components.Mantissa);
    printf("Exponent: %#010x\n", result.Components.Exponent);
    printf("Sign:     %#010x\n", result.Components.Sign);
    return 0;
}
```

In the example I would expect my Mantissa to be 0x00000054, the exponent to be 0x0000001F, and sign 0x00000001

Instead I get Mantissa: 0x0000013f, Exponent: 0x00000005, Sign: 0x00000000

Which means that from my bit mask first the Sign was taken (first bit), next 5 bits to exponent, then 10 bit to mantissa, so the order is inverse of what I wanted. Why is that happening?

Comment: Note: it doesn't even look like endianess or something, the whole struct is in the wrong order for whatever reason

Comment: Note: Reading from any field other than the active one in a union is formally Undefined Behavior. Your compiler _may_ make it legal (either by default or through a switch), but type punning via unions is not standard-compliant C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitfields and alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668466/bitfields-and-alignment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The worse part is that a different compiler could give the expected order. The standard has never specified the implementation details for bitfields, and specifically the order. The rationale being as usual that it is an implementation detail and that programmers should not rely nor depend on that.

The downside is that it is not possible to use bitfields in cross language programs, and that programmers cannot use bitfields for processing data having well known bitfields (for example in network protocol headers) because it is too complex to make sure how the implementation will process them.

For that reason I have always thought that it was just an unuseable feature and I only use bitmask on unsigned types instead of bitfields. But that last part is no more than my own opinion...

Comment: So back to bitshifting, and instead make it better readable... gotcha

Comment: @SinisterMJ `<rank>` yes it is a pity. Looks like the standardisation group has forgotten that a language had to be used for real world programs`</rant>`. The language is like that and we have to accept it...

Comment: because it is "not" too complex to make - Is 'not' intended?

Comment: @Ajay: Of course not! It was a typo :-(. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 2):

I would say your `input` is incorrect, for this compiler anyway. This is what the `float16_and_int16` order looks like.

```
 sign   exponent  mantissa
 [15]   [14:10]    [9:0]
```

or

```
SGN |  E  X  P  O  N  E  N  T|     M  A   N   T   I   S   S   A                |
 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 09 | 08 | 07 | 06 | 05 | 04 | 03 | 02 | 01 | 00 |
```

if  `input = 0x153F` then `bitMask ==`

```
SGN |  E  X  P  O  N  E  N  T|     M  A   N   T   I   S   S   A                |
 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 09 | 08 | 07 | 06 | 05 | 04 | 03 | 02 | 01 | 00 |
 0     0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

so

```
MANTISSA == 0100111111  (0x13F)
EXPONENT == 00101 (0x5)
SIGN == 0 (0x0)
```

If you want mantissa to be 0x54, exponent 0x1f and sign 0x1 you need

```
SGN |  E  X  P  O  N  E  N  T|     M  A   N   T   I   S   S   A                |
 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 09 | 08 | 07 | 06 | 05 | 04 | 03 | 02 | 01 | 00 |
 1     1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0
```

or

```
input = 0xFC64
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, the point is, why is the order in the bitfield sign -> exponent -> mantissa. I defined it in inverse order of that.

Comment: when you define struct in a union as bitfield, this first that is defined is the least significant. This kind of makes sense, if you only have a few bits, they will be aligned to the right to fill the least significant bits